# Принудительная остановка таймера

Tags: таймер, java

Всем привет. Я использую следующий код для работы с таймером, каким способом его можно остановить раньше планируемого времени?

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     final int msek = (int) millisUntilFinished/10; // получаем мсек
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(Time)+"."+String.valueOf(msek));
    }
  public void onFinish() {
    }
 }.start();
```

Comment: ну судя по тому, что в нем всего 4 метода и один из них cancel, то наверное он...

Comment: Это же очевидно! Спасибо.

Comment: ничего не понятно,как им пользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала сохраните в отдельную переменную:

```
 CountDownTimer myTimer= new CountDownTimer(...
```

А потом вызывайте метод cancel:

```
myTimer.cancel();
```